# Can I start apodosis with the phrase 'I'm going to'?

Tags: conditional-constructions

**Sentence:**

> When McDonald makes it happen I'm going to try the sausage out

Protasis:

> When McDonald makes it happen

Apodosis:

> I'm going to try the sausage out

Question:

> Can I start apodosis with the phrase **'I'm going to', 'I maybe', 'Probably I will go', 'I think I will'**

Comment: It's not a conditional construction, so there is no protasis or apodosis. The subordinate clause "When McD's makes it happen" is a temporal adjunct, not a conditional. Virtually all conditionals begin with "if".

Answer (score 1):

In your example of *condition* and *consequence*

> probably
>   maybe

should not be used in the *consequence* since certainty is needed

> When McDonald makes it happen
>
> I *am going to* try the sausage out
>   I *will try* the sausage out

Comment: What if I want to express some uncertainty like _('I maybe', 'Probably I will go', 'I think I will')_ ?. It must be some option in terms of conditional structure